# Stored procedure : query optimization

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

The system had a stored procedure with 7 selects and uniting this using UNION. I have optimized but the query is still slow.

Is there any way to do it faster?

I tried do it faster using `CASE`, but is still slow. The time to execute is one minute.

*Which indexes should I create, according to the query below?*

**CODE**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_DEN_S_CONTROLE_DIARIO]
(
    @CLI_N_CODIGO NUMERIC(18),
    @DATA_CONSULTA DATETIME 
)
AS

DECLARE @DATA AS DATE = DBO.FUN_DEN_DATA_SEM_HORA(@DATA_CONSULTA)

SELECT DISTINCT
    PAC.PAC_N_CODIGO,
    PAC.PAC_C_NOME,
    PAC.PAC_C_MATRICULA,
    PAC.PAC_D_ULTIMA_VISITA,
    CASE ODO.ODO_PTR_N_CODIGO 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'S'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'N'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS ORCAMENTO,
    CTR.CTR_C_CODINTELIGENTE,
    CTR.CTR_N_VALOR_RECEBIDO,
    (SELECT SUM(VIN_N_VALOR) FROM DEN_VIN_VINCULO_TRATAMENTO WHERE VIN_OXD_ODO_N_CODIGO = ODO_N_CODIGO) AS VALOR_ORC,

    CASE WHEN CTR.CTR_DET_N_CODIGO IS NULL THEN 
        (SELECT DET_C_NOME FROM DEN_DET_DENTISTA WHERE DET_N_CODIGO = PAC.PAC_DET_N_CODIGO AND DET_CLI_N_CODIGO = @CLI_N_CODIGO)
    ELSE    
        (SELECT DET_C_NOME FROM DEN_DET_DENTISTA WHERE DET_N_CODIGO = CTR.CTR_DET_N_CODIGO AND DET_CLI_N_CODIGO = @CLI_N_CODIGO)
    END AS DENTISTA,

    CASE WHEN ODO.ODO_PTR_N_CODIGO IS NULL AND CTR.CTR_N_VALOR_RECEBIDO IS NULL
    THEN
        CASE WHEN 
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
            DEN_VIN_VINCULO_TRATAMENTO INNER JOIN DEN_ODO_ODONTOGRAMA ON VIN_OXD_ODO_N_CODIGO = ODO_N_CODIGO 
        WHERE 
            ODO_PAC_N_CODIGO = PAC_N_CODIGO AND ODO_B_ATIVO = 1 
        AND
            (
                DBO.FUN_DEN_DATA_SEM_HORA(ODO_D_DATA_CADASTRO) = @DATA
            OR
                DBO.FUN_DEN_DATA_SEM_HORA(VIN_D_DATA_REALIZADO) = @DATA
            OR
                DBO.FUN_DEN_DATA_SEM_HORA(VIN_D_DATA_CADASTRO) = @DATA
            )
        ) = 0
        THEN
            '1'
        ELSE
            '0'
        END 
    ELSE
        '0'
    END AS SEM_AGENDAMENTO
FROM
    DEN_PAC_PACIENTE PAC
LEFT JOIN
    DEN_CTR_CONTA_RECEBER CTR ON (CTR.CTR_PAC_N_CODIGO = PAC.PAC_N_CODIGO) 
                              AND CTR.CTR_B_ATIVO = 1
                              AND (DBO.FUN_DEN_DATA_SEM_HORA(CTR.CTR_D_DATA_RECEBIMENTO) = @DATA)
LEFT JOIN
    DEN_ODO_ODONTOGRAMA ODO ON (ODO.ODO_N_CODIGO = CTR.CTR_ODO_N_CODIGO 
                                OR 
                                (ODO.ODO_PAC_N_CODIGO = PAC.PAC_N_CODIGO 
                                 AND 
                                 (ODO_B_APROVADO = 0 OR ODO_B_APROVADO IS NULL))
                                )
                            AND DBO.FUN_DEN_DATA_SEM_HORA(ODO.ODO_D_DATA_CADASTRO) = @DATA
WHERE
    PAC.PAC_B_ATIVO = 1
    AND DBO.FUN_DEN_DATA_SEM_HORA(PAC.PAC_D_ULTIMA_VISITA) = @DATA
    AND PAC.PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO = @CLI_N_CODIGO
ORDER BY
    PAC.PAC_D_ULTIMA_VISITA
```

Comment: `I have optimized but the query is still slow.` How did you know what to optimize?  Did you review the execution plan?  Do you have proper indexes on the tables?

Comment: I remade the query. I'm a web developer, I have not much knowledge to the database. I wanted an opinion about the query.

Comment: Kind of tough to read... Can you move the subselects that are within the fields you are selecting to the FROM clause using joins?

Comment: Have you tried re-creating the query from scratch adding everything bit by bit and noticing when a major difference in performance happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a #temp table and insert all the records into it. I assume that since you are using Union, all of your select queries must return same number of coulmns with same data type. Do not use union while inserting records into temp table. At the end, select * from temp table.

Inserting records into temp table through separate select queries will be faster than 7 union select queries.